# Stupefyingly weird IE 9 Javascript bug: Altering doc title makes subsequent code execute

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I don't understand this at all. Here is some Javascript code that works in every browser but IE 9. It is called from a Flash movie using `ExternalInterface`, and is meant to dynamically resize the movie in the DOM if the size of the movie changes internally

```
function vResizeFlash(swfId, ht) {
    document.getElementById(swfId).height = "100%";
    document.getElementById('flashContainer').style.height = ht + "px";
}
```

But it works fine if I alter the document.title:

```
function vResizeFlash(swfId, ht) {
    // IE 9 won't run the rest of this function unless
    // we go through the charade of changing the document title.
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
       var docTitle = document.title.replace(/^(.+?)\s*$/,"$1");
       document.title = docTitle + " ";
    }
    // Well-coded browsers begin here
    document.getElementById(swfId).height = "100%";
    document.getElementById('flashContainer').style.height = ht + "px";
}
```

Here I simply trim any white-space from the right side of the `document.title`, then add a single white-space character to it. Suddenly the following lines get executed. Note: there are other `ExternalInterface` calls on the page, and all of them work fine, even in IE 9, so it's not a Flash/IE 9 problem.

I stumbled on the fix because I was altering the title to show the function arguments (as a quick debugging test), just to make sure the function was getting run. And suddenly the code worked. Take it out? Doesn't work. 100% reproducible.

Anybody know *why* this absolutely stupefying behavior takes place?

**UPDATE**

@c69 has posed the question: "Maybe its IE9's dead code remover?"

I didn't know about this, so I went and Googled and found [this article](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/11/lies-damned-lies-and-benchmarks-is-ie9-cheating-at-sunspider.ars/2) on the topic, as well as [some discussion](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1917374) of it elsewhere. I don't know enough about it to evaluate how this would affect a two-line Javascript function, however, especially since one of the lines does have a referent on the page (although it is late-loading through the SwfObject code). Still, it would be a pretty bad bug for a code "optimizer" to remove lines of code it deemed unnecessary because it doesn't understand how they are called. And if it *did* fail to understand how the lines are called, how does inserting a line making a bogus change to the document.title render that code suddenly "necessary"?

**UPDATE 2**

Another piece of the puzzle This may have something to do with IE 9's compatibility mode. The page starts out in IE 9's standards mode.

[image]

Now, if I turn on IE's compatibility mode,

[image]

the problem goes away without using the above hack. Turn it off, and the problem returns (if no hack present).

But when I tried to make a simple test using the exact same HTML (minus a couple of JSP  tags) and a stripped down SWF that only contains the resize code and the tools to test, everything works fine. In *that* case, however, no compatibility icon is displayed at all.

[image]

We're using Tomcat 6.0.32. I'm not aware that we are using any special headers, and there are no meta tags regarding IE compatibility mode (in either the main app or in my test app).

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Or does it just plain not run?

Comment: Why are you setting something's height to `100%`? That usually has no meaning in terms of resizing something. Not particularly germane to your original problem, however, changing that code may make your problem disappear.

Comment: Does it have to be a title change? Or can it be any other code, even something simple like `var junk = null;`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? I know IE debugger is a pain... but may throw something out

Comment: @Kolink: It just doesn't run. @Tejs: This is how you resize a fixed-size Flash movie. Trust me. @Marc B: Simply creating variables doesn't work. Setting `document.title = document.title` also doesn't work. @Chuck Birkin: I haven't the time to fool with this right now. I've checked in this fix to make a release deadline, but I really would like to know WTF.

Comment: Could you please post a link to live demo?

Comment: What sub-version of IE9 ? could it be you are using a beta version of IE 9 ?

Comment: @Gaby: 9.0.8112.16421, Update Version: 9.0.2(KB25599049). Not a beta. duri: I will when I get more time. Just swamped atm.

Comment: When you say "It just doesn't run" do you mean that if you'd placed an alert() call in that function it wouldn't be called?  Or do you mean that those 2 lines of codes have no effect?

Comment: @pcantin: I mean those two lines of code do not get executed. Putting in an alert (which I just tried) also permits the two lines to execute.

Comment: Maybe its IE9's _dead code remover_ ?

Comment: @c69: This is interesting. I didn't know that existed, but it could be an explanation.

Comment: @Robusto Could it be that those parameters are only read during a load/refresh of the flash element?  In this case, modifying the page title could be triggering that load/refresh this flash element.

Comment: @pcantin: All aspects of the Flash element work. This is an external call, and the error involves that one Javascript function. In other words, the call would not get made if the Flash movie did not work or was not present.

Comment: Does adding: if (1 == 0) { vResizeFlash('the id', 100); } cause it to work? (Just add into the global scope somewhere)

Comment: Are you sure the DOM has been parsed completely before those lines ever execute?  Maybe set a flag to true when the window loads and check that the flag is true before accessing DOM elements? (Though, not sure why setting title would change that)

Comment: Does reversing the order of the lines `document.getElementById(swfId).height = "100%";` and `document.getElementById('flashContainer').style.height = ht + "px";` have any effect?

Comment: @John Kurlak: I would think that IE would try to optimize for something like `if (1 == 0)`. But it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: what does your <!DOCTYPE> tag look like?

Comment: is your test running locally? By default IE puts local pages in the Intranet zone, and it renders Intranet zone pages in Compatibility Mode by default, for the benefit of crappy corpo-intranets. If this is the case the Compatibility icon won't be displayed, but you can verify the current mode with the Developer Tools. You can change all these defaults though.

Comment: @Graham: Yes, I'm running it locally. I really should run it through the server, though, on an identical (almost) JSP page. I will try that tomorrow. Oh, and thanks for the info.

Comment: If IE9 is even offering you a compatibility icon, than it thinks there is something incompatible in your page.  Can we see a live version of the page, please?

Comment: @graphicdivine: I can't make our dev servers available to the public. Do you know a (free) site where I can upload Flash and JSP and have it run?

Comment: @invertedSpear: Standard doctype output by Flex html template: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`. I've tried it with other doctypes, though, including `<!DOCTYPE html>`, with the same result.

Comment: Read this article on how to use compatibility mode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#Content . You can enforce it using a <meta> tag.

Comment: @Robusto Your doctype may be xhtml, but is the content-type? Try serving as `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @kzh: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: [XHTML Myths and Realities](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/xhtml.html) is a good read. First off, your content-type is html, not xhtml, and 2nd, you NEED to have your http header to say that it's XHTML, not your meta tag. Some, (maybe most) will not care what that meta tag says and will just render HTML. My advice is for you to change your doctype to `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: @kzh: As I mentioned above, I've tried that doctype, with no change in behavior.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with a small flash app that I've made: http://brian.peiris.name/so/7491790/

Comment: Sorry, Rubusto, if you can't make a public version of this I don't think I can help.  Can't fix if if I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like InvertedSpear mentions, check your doc type out, i've had problems with IE9 recently and most of it boiled down to the Doc type tags triggering a compatability mode i didn't need, the same can be true of the meta tags so it might boil down to your Meta tags.

You can always impose a working compatibility mode using the links below too.

from: http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/ie9-compatibility-and-the-meta-tag/

I’ve discovered that this is indeed documented by Microsoft…

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

“The X-UA-Compatible header is not case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements.”

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see something like this happen in any language it's because there is other code that has a bug.  As you pointed out your simple case doesn't produce the problem.  Try removing other code a few lines at a time until the problem disappears - the last removed code should contain the problem.

Cheers